# Why is my hook variable in React not holding the state I set it to?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am using React and Redux. When my props.employees changes for the 1st time, useEffect runs and updates my teamsArr to the value of props.employees.

But my desire is to add the props.employees array to the teamsArr array that should already be filled with the previous props.employees array values.

But instead, whenever I change the value of props.employees, my teamsArr variable is initially empty and then changes the value to solely the current props.employees value.

I've been struggling to figure out how to solve this, so any help would be very welcome.

```
const Employees = (props) => {
    const [teamsArr, setTeamsArr] = useState([])


    useEffect(() => {
        const updatedTeamsArr = [...teamsArr, props.employees]
        setTeamsArr(updatedTeamsArr)
        }
    ,[props.employees])
```

Comment: depending on what your data looks like if you use @Robert's answer check if the data already exists in your array before updating your array, otherwise you will be adding dups.

Comment: Storing props that change as part of the state of component seems a very odd thing to do.  Generally speaking functional components are meant to be predictable, your trying to bypass that logic, and I feel it's going to cause lots of issues.   Is this maybe XY problem?

Comment: what You want merge or update?

Comment: Agreed, generally it is considered anti-pattern in React to store passed props in local component state. What is the use case and goal for doing this? There is often a clearer and more straight forward way that avoids stale state/state synchronicity issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of passing a function to setTeamsArr

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTeamsArr(prev => [...prev, ...props.employees])
    }
,[props.employees])
```

but in this case everytime prop.employees changes it'll be added but old values won't be removed.

Comment: whats role of `prev` will play here, is it old or current values, which will get updated with  `props.employees`

Comment: Yes, I'm with @AshishKamble here.  The effect has `props.employees` as a dependency, as such it's not going to be stale anyway, and that's the point of `prev => ....`  callback's..